# How to hide and show my app dialpad number

Tags: android, show

I am using the following code to hide the app from the menu:

```
 PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
                    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(MainActivity2.this,
                            com.example.testdial.MainActivity2.class);
                    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
                            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

It's working fine, but when I tried to show the hidden app by using this:

```
PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager();
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context,MainActivity2.class);
            p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

It does not work for me. I searched for a long time in Stack Overflow and Google, but none of the code helped to me. Is there any other way to hide and show my app?